# Android: Reset Parse backend object everyday, week and month

Tags: android, parse-platform, alarmmanager, reset

I am trying to reset parse int objects everyday, week and month using Alarm Manager. I have three objects dayObject, weekObject and monthObject which runs and updates the text views. But the app is crashing with error Value May Not be Null. Please help!!!

`onCreate()`:

```
Intent iToday = new Intent(this, TodayReset.class);
iToday.putExtra("createdAt", createdAt.getTime());
piToday = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iToday, 0);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, today.getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, piToday);
```

On Receive(): I am getting today, week and month dates from Calendar. Then I check the conditions and update the Parse backend.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Pattern");

query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
   @Override
   public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
     if(e == null && object != null) {
       totalValue = object.getInt("totalValue");
       weekValue = object.getInt("weekValue");
       monthValue = object.getInt("monthValue");            
     } else {
       Log.i("RetErr", e.getMessage());
     }
   }
});

ParseObject pattern = new ParseObject("Pattern");

pattern.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

pattern.put("totalValue", totalValue);
pattern.put("todayValue", 0);
pattern.put("weekValue", weekValue);
pattern.put("monthValue", monthValue);

pattern.save();
```

I am repeating the same for week and month. I am retrieving all objects because when I save only a particular object, then the other objects show not defined. Hence I retrieve the old value and save it again.

Comment: Sounds like something that should be handled by your backend

Comment: Secondly, why not just store the date? You can pull day, week, month etc from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the creation of the new Parse Object inside done() like below. Because the query is done in the background is doesnt finish before you try and use totalValue etc.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Pattern");

        query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {

                if(e == null && object != null) {

                    totalValue = object.getInt("totalValue");
                    weekValue = object.getInt("weekValue");
                    monthValue = object.getInt("monthValue");
                    ParseObject pattern = new ParseObject("Pattern");

        pattern.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

        pattern.put("totalValue", totalValue);
        pattern.put("todayValue", 0);
        pattern.put("weekValue", weekValue);
        pattern.put("monthValue", monthValue);

            pattern.save();


                } else {

                    Log.i("RetErr", e.getMessage());

                }

            }

        });
```